# Apache Superset redirecting to IP in production

Tags: docker, flask, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I have a superset application which I have dockerized based on the docker instructions(https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#start-with-docker). It works fine locally but keeps redirecting to the containers ip in production.
I have tried (https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/1866#issuecomment-335272079). I also tried the flask redirect solution (http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/). Yet nothing seems to work. Can anyone help. Or does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Josir Sadly I don't remember how I resolved it. And I'm no longer working on that project. Sorry if I could not be of any help.